# How to hide the date mask in asp TextBox with TextMode="Date"

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I'm still using the old asp.NET 4.8, and testing asp:TextBox with Date TextMode, e.g.

```
 <label>ASP TextBox</label><br />
 <asp:TextBox ID="dateTB0" runat="server" TextMode="Date" ></asp:TextBox><br />
```

When there is no value, it displays the mask like this:
[image]

Is it possible to hide the mask when there is no value?

**UPDATE**:
With Chrome developers tool, it treats asp:TextBox as `input[type="date"]` but any approaches playing with the CSS are completely ignored. Note that when I tested `<input type='date'/>`, those CSS approaches worked.  So, this question is specific to `asp:TextBox`.

Comment: This is the browser's standard behavior for an `<input type="date">`.  Taking a step back... Why do you need to override this behavior?  Do you want this to be a normal text input instead?  Something else?

Comment: No, it is just ugly. We used a custom control which didn't display the mask. So, if I replace that control by asp:TextBox, the existing users will complain.

Comment: In that case the linked duplicates are a good place to start for customizing the input.  There are a handful of approaches taken, some of which are a bit browser-dependent since this is browser behavior.